# Convex function or concave function.

Tags: convex-analysis

1. Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a closed and convex set,  then prove that for each $x \in D$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ the function

\begin{equation*}
    \varphi_{1}: \mathbb{R}_{+}\to \mathbb{R}, \hspace{3mm} \varphi_{1}(t)=\|P_{D}(x+td)-x\|,
   \end{equation*}
is a monotone non-decreasing function.

2. Prove that  \begin{equation*}
       \varphi_{2}: (\mathbb{R}_{+}\setminus \{0\})\to \mathbb{R}, \hspace{3mm} \varphi_{2}(t)=\frac{\varphi_{1}(t)}{t},
      \end{equation*}
   is a monotone non-increasing function.

I'm able to prove the first item and I'm trying to prove that the function $-\varphi_{2}(t)$ is a increasing function.  My attempt: Let $\beta \geq \alpha >0$, then there exists  $t \in (0,1]$ such that  $\alpha = t\beta= (1-t)0+t\beta$. Here I'm stuck since  I want to use that  $-\varphi_{1}(t)$ is a convex function, but I can't prove this afirmation. This work or are there other form?

Thanks!

Comment: What is meant by $P_D$?

Comment: Hi @JKL , is the projection onto the set D.

Comment: Might it help to check for "perspective function"